# Snapping Issue in Illustrator - Unable to Move Anchor Points Specifically

Tags: adobe-illustrator, snapping

I'm not sure how else to describe this - the anchor points are 'snapping' to undesired locations.

This has happened many, many times - it's very frustrating.

I'll be working in Illustrator and then, for some reason, out of nowhere, Illustrator stops letting me be specific with where I can drag my anchor points to.

Take a look at the following screenshots.

I start with my anchor point here:

[image]

If I try to move that anchor point over to the right just barely, it **jumps** from there to **here**:

[image]

That's quite the distance:

[image]

And there is no in-between. Same with trying to move the anchor point down, or anywhere else.

[image]

Why is this happening? Is anyone else having the same issue? I was experiencing this problem in Illustrator 2019 and it seemed to have just kindof gone away. But now, it's back and it happens all the time for me in Illustrator 2020. It's as if the anchor points have become pixelated.

Is there a solution? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Either you have gridsnap or pixelsnap on. i instead of the properties panel you used the top toolbaar there would be a toggle switch visible gor pixel snap which is the likely culprit.

Comment: Yes! The issue was pixelsnap! I don't know how it suddenly turned on - there doesn't seem to be a keyboard command for it. But I got rid of it simply by going to View and unchecking "Snap to Pixel". Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @joojaa pointed out, the issue in this case was Pixelsnap. I don't know how it go turned on, but to disable it, I just went to View and unchecked "Snap to Pixel". And just like that it's back to normal.

Comment: The RGB document profiles sturn pixelsnap on when you open a document. (personally i have disabled pixel snap, i never use it, even when i have a pixel perfect image i just adjust my snapping to 1/2 pixel)